# Inclusion of a dyadic interval in another dyadic interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

This problem is supposed to be very trivial, but I'm losing my mind over it. Given that 
$j_0 >j_1$ and $k_0 > k_1$, one and only one of these three cases must hold:

$1)\quad \left[\dfrac{k_0}{2^{j_{0}}},\dfrac{k_0+1}{2^{j_{0}}} \right) \subseteq \left[\dfrac{k_1}{2^{j_{1}}},\dfrac{k_1+1}{2^{j_{1}}} \right) $

$2)\quad  \left[\dfrac{k_0}{2^{j_{0}}},\dfrac{k_0+1}{2^{j_{0}}} \right) \supseteq \left[\dfrac{k_1}{2^{j_{1}}},\dfrac{k_1+1}{2^{j_{1}}} \right) $

$3)\quad \left[\dfrac{k_0}{2^{j_{0}}},\dfrac{k_0+1}{2^{j_{0}}} \right) \cap \left[\dfrac{k_1}{2^{j_{1}}},\dfrac{k_1+1}{2^{j_{1}}} \right) = \emptyset$

My vain idea is that if the supremum of one the intervals is less than the infimum of the other interval, then the job is done. Shockingly I can't show this because I can't compare the boundaries. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the interval on the right is longer than the one on the left, so the second case *can't* hold.

Comment: Right. I might as well delete the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following inequalities: $$\frac{k_1}{2^{j_1}}\leq\frac{k_0}{2^{j_0}}<\frac{k_1+1}{2^{j_1}}\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ $$\frac{k_1}{2^{j_1}}<\frac{k_0+1}{2^{j_0}}\leq\frac{k_1+1}{2^{j_1}}\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$

Your goal should be to show that $(\heartsuit)$ holds if and only if $(\diamondsuit)$ holds. From this, you can show that the first case holds if and only if the third case *fails* to hold.

---

The claim (as it stands) is fairly awkwardly phrased and over-specific. More generally, we can say the following:

> Suppose $k_0,k_1$ are integers and that $j_0,j_1$ are non-negative integers such that $$\left[\frac{k_0}{2^{j_0}},\frac{k_0+1}{2^{j_0}}\right)\neq \left[\frac{k_1}{2^{j_1}},\frac{k_1+1}{2^{j_1}}\right).$$ Then exactly one of the following holds: $$\left[\frac{k_0}{2^{j_0}},\frac{k_0+1}{2^{j_0}}\right)\subsetneq \left[\frac{k_1}{2^{j_1}},\frac{k_1+1}{2^{j_1}}\right)\tag{1}$$ $$\left[\frac{k_0}{2^{j_0}},\frac{k_0+1}{2^{j_0}}\right)\supsetneq \left[\frac{k_1}{2^{j_1}},\frac{k_1+1}{2^{j_1}}\right)\tag{2}$$ $$\left[\frac{k_0}{2^{j_0}},\frac{k_0+1}{2^{j_0}}\right)\cap\left[\frac{k_1}{2^{j_1}},\frac{k_1+1}{2^{j_1}}\right)=\emptyset.\tag{3}$$ In particular, $(1)$ cannot happen unless $j_0>j_1,$ and $(2)$ cannot happen unless $j_0<j_1,$ so $(3)$ *must* happen if $j_0=j_1.$